# I couldn't login with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I tried to login into GitHub with this code and It worked! But I couldn't be able to login to this site any help, please. I tried to take a screenshot and I noticed that the user name filed and password are never filled in...

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


const USERNAME_SELECTOR = 'input[name=UserName]';
const PASSWORD_SELECTOR = 'input[name=Password]';


const url = 'https://www.itemsatis.com/';

(async function () {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ["--disable-notifications"] });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });

  page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector('.close', { visible: true, timeout: 3000 }).click();
  });

  page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector('.LoginButton', { visible: true, timeout: 3000 }).click();
  });

  await page.focus('#loginForm', { visible: true, timeout: 3000 });
  await page.keyboard.type(USERNAME_SELECTOR, 'Monaliza', { visible: true, timeout: 3000 });

  await page.keyboard.type(PASSWORD_SELECTOR, 'asdfgh123', { visible: true, timeout: 3000 });

 
  await Promise.all([
    page.evaluate(() => {
      document.querySelector('.loginSubmitBtn', { visible: true, timeout: 3000 }).click();
    })
  ]);
  await page.goto('https://www.itemsatis.com/favori-ilanlarim.html', { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'login.png' });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method didn't work for me, I logged in by POST request.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const url = 'https://www.itemsatis.com/favori-ilanlarim.html';

(async function () {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, args: ["--disable-notifications"], ignoreHTTPSErrors: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    page.on("request", interceptedRequest => {
        var dataa = {
            "method": "POST",
            "timeout": 0,
            "headers": {
                "authority": "www.itemsatis.com",
                "pragma": "no-cache",
                "cache-control": "no-cache",
                "sec-ch-ua": "\"Chromium\";v=\"88\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"88\", \";Not A Brand\";v=\"99\"",
                "accept": "*/*",
                "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
                "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
                "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36",
                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                "origin": "https://www.itemsatis.com",
                "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
                "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
                "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
                "referer": "https://www.itemsatis.com/index.php",
                "accept-language": "tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ar;q=0.6",
                "cookie": "__cfduid=defaba322e491fa341a871e5e478e013d1612073699; PHPSESSID=9srle1dn5mkrhvlpbh0vcc07dk; _gid=GA1.2.1212422826.1612073704; __tawkuuid=e::itemsatis.com::A9bReKylE+WK1xjhjJnun2iiOJfMOqWH0EO/d1oqMV3w4iv9oh14EwP5hiOzN+gg::2; PopupReklam=1; _ga_ZN0SH1X916=GS1.1.1612104459.5.0.1612104459.0; _ga=GA1.2.1639157910.1612073704; TawkConnectionTime=0; __cfduid=d5e64e52823bb5077dc927279177d8fdb1612090326; PHPSESSID=46vsasvpruaolue7lp4krlujjv"
            },
            "data": "UserName=your_username&Password=your_password&csrf_token=a2df55e8ca409fe524775411939d13c6",
        };
        interceptedRequest.continue(dataa);
    });

    const response = await page.goto(url);
    //  console.log(await response.text());
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'loginn.png' });

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use [`page.keyboard.type()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.4.1/docs/api.md#keyboardtypetext-options) correctly.

The documentation says it accepts 2 arguments:

> - `text` <string> A text to type into a focused element.
> - `options` <Object>

But you're passing in 3 arguments, selector being the first one:

```js
await page.keyboard.type(USERNAME_SELECTOR, 'Monaliza', { visible: true, timeout: 3000 });
```

If you remove the selector, then you still don't follow the documentation because it types into a focused element, and you focus the whole login form, not only the input or password fields.

If you want to input text into an input field, usually, you can do it with [`page.type()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.4.1/docs/api.md#pagetypeselector-text-options):

```js
await page.type(USERNAME_SELECTOR, 'Monaliza');
```

or [`elementHandle.type()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.4.1/docs/api.md#elementhandletypetext-options):

```js
const userNameField = await page.$(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
await userNameField.type('Monaliza');
```

Try to correct your code according these examples, it might solve your problem.

---

I also recommend learning how to debug such problems, it consists of at least 3 steps:

- running Puppeteer in a headful mode, i.e. setting `headless` property to `false`
- slowing down the whole execution, i.e. setting `slowMo` property
- using breakpoints and then manually stepping through the code (depends a bit on your IDE, but it's possible)

These 3 actions will usually help you in resolving most of the problems you might have with Puppeteer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still doesn't work, actually I didn't work on puppeteer before and I need it for a job application :/ hope I can figure it ASAP.

Comment: There might be more problems, I focused on what you said in text. E.g. you're not awaiting `page.evaluate()`, `document.querySelector()` doesn't accept any option object, so passing `{ visible: true, timeout: 3000 }` is not necessary, it might even cause some error (not sure off the top of my head). But I recommend following my debugging advice, you always have the API documentation. If it's a job application, then it seems you'll need this in the job, so sooner or later you need to learn it anyway, you can't expect to come to SO every time you face some problem.